# Installing gnuradio and getting missing dependencies

Tags: python, linux, gnuradio

I'm working off a linux mint machine, trying to install gnuradio from source.
When it's configuring VOLK support, it says:

```
Python checking for python >= 2.7 -found
Python checking for mako>= 0.4.2 - not found
Python checking for six -python 2 and 3 compatibility library -not found
```

And then it says error installing package gnuradio.

I tried running `sudo apt-get install -y python3-mako`

```
-->  python3 mako is already the newest version
```

I also ran `pip3 install six`:

```
 --> requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

So I'm not sure what to do from here. Could this be a python version problem, as in do I have to use python2 instead of 3?

Comment: if it checks `python >= 2.7` then maybe it needs `Python 2` and you should use `pip2` instead of `pip3` - `pip2 install six mako`

Comment: I'm not able to download pip2 though. I tried sudo apt-get install python-pip, python2-pip. Terminal just says unable to locate package.

Comment: teoretically all new `Python 2` should have installed `pip2` but I see it still needs to download `get_pip.py` from page https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by installing a previous version of mako. It seems that the gnu radio installer ([pybombs](https://github.com/gnuradio/pybombs) for me ) does not recognize the major version number, just the minor.

On Fedora running:

`python3 -m pip install mako==0.8.0`

before the installer, worked for me.